# C++ compile error. G++ gnu

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Hi I am having some issues with my c++ program. I am using g++ gnu and it is on windows 10. here is the error that is showing up:

ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

please help because i can not work out what is going on.

Thanks,
Asher

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: `ld.exe`? are you sure you use GNU?

Answer (score 0):

That is a *linker* error. Not a *compiler* error.
It is complaining that it cannot find the pthread library in the library search path. Either it simply isn't there or you need to indicate where it is with the `-L` option. Or, in case pthread is not needed, remove the `-lpthread` option so you don't attempt to link to it.

Comment: how do i do this?